# VLC: How to delete file on disk

Tags: linux-mint, vlc-media-player

I download videos from Youtube to watch later. I use VLC to watch the videos and when I am done watching a video I would like to remove the file on disk directly from VLC.

I have found several guides on how to implement this, but none of them work for me:

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=108811
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=113813
http://addons.videolan.org/CONTENT/content-files/153041-Diskdelete.lua

If I follow those nothing happens: No buttons and if there is a keyboard shortcut I am not being told.

So how do I get a button/keyboard shortcut in VLC to delete the video file currently playing from disk?

I use VLC 2.0.8 on GNU/Linux Mint.

Comment: Got a link or two to the guide(s) that didn't work for you?  How exactly did it fail?  It would be useful to see exactly what they are suggesting, and to know how it failed for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So put the file in ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions. I call it DeleteFile.lua.

When you start VLC you get a new menu item: View > Detetefile. It is this last step I was missing.

*Edit 20200306*

The code did not work very well. I changed it:

https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/blob/master/wastebasket/dotlocal/share/vlc/lua/extensions/WasteBasket.lua

It now searches for a dir called `.waste` in the dir of the file and any (grand*)parent dirs, and moves the file there. So you need to create a dir called `.waste`.

When you start VLC you get a new menu item: View > Move currently playing file into wastebasket.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.

Comment: For me neither, but adding the lua file to the directory makes it appear in *VLC File Menu > Extensions > Diskdelete*. But clicking it does nothing, and *View > Deletefile* does not appear.

Comment: This works as expected.

Comment: gitlab blob is dead,  can anyone post the script in here?

Comment: @Mash Fixed URL for gitlab.

Comment: Everything appears to work except the actual move into the `.waste` folder ? (On Windows)

Comment: @MartinEvans If you find a solution to that on Windows, feel free to raise an issue, so it can be fixed (it might due to GNU/Linux using / instead of \, which should be easy to fix - or it might be due to Windows not allowing rename of a file being played, which is probably harder to fix).

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/PAEz/d3a9be2471dbd39084136d974cdb9dd3

```
--[[
    Copyright 2015-2016 surrim
    https://gist.github.com/PAEz/d3a9be2471dbd39084136d974cdb9dd3
    https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=108811
    https://superuser.com/questions/721112/vlc-how-to-delete-file-on-disk#
    This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.
    This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.
    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
]]--

function descriptor()
    return {
        title = "VLC Delete";
        version = "0.1";
        author = "surrim";
        url = "https://github.com/surrim/vlc-delete/";
        shortdesc = "Remove current file from playlist and disk";
        description = [[
<h1>vlc-delete</h1>"
When you're playing a file, use VLC Delete to
delete the current file from your playlist and <b>disk</b> with one click.<br>
This extension has been tested on GNU Linux with VLC 2.1.5.<br>
The author is not responsible for damage caused by this extension.
        ]];
   }
end


-- Windows - Check if file exists
function fileExists(file)
    return io.popen("if exist "..file.." (echo 1)"):read'*l'=='1'
end


function sleep(n)  -- seconds
  local t0 = os.clock()
  local tOriginal=t0
  while os.clock() - t0 <= n and os.clock()>=tOriginal do end
end


-- Windows - try and delete a file with multiple attempts and a pause between each try - waiting for the file to unlock
function windowsDelete(file,trys,pause)
    if not fileExists('"'..file..'"') then return nil,'File does not exist' end
    for i = trys,1,-1
    do
        retval, err = os.remove(file)
        --retval, err = os.execute('del ' .. file )
        if retval==true then
            return true
        end
        sleep(pause) -- wish i had a better timer than one second, want misc.mdate..could just bash it but you shouldnt ever wait more than one second so meh
    end
    return {nil,'Unable to delete file'}
end

function removeItem()
    local id = vlc.playlist.current()
    vlc.playlist.delete(id)
    vlc.playlist.gotoitem(id + 1)
    vlc.deactivate()
end

function activate()
    local item = vlc.input.item()
    local uri = item:uri()
    uri = string.gsub(uri, '^file:///', '')
    uri = vlc.strings.decode_uri(uri)
    vlc.msg.info("[vlc-delete] removing: " .. uri)
    -- check for non windows
    if (package.config:sub(1,1) == "/") then
        retval, err = os.execute("trash-put --help > /dev/null")
        if (retval ~= nil) then
            uri = "/" .. uri
            retval, err = os.execute("trash-put \"" .. uri .. "\"")
        else
            retval, err = os.execute("rm --help > /dev/null")
            if (retval ~= nil) then
                uri = "/" .. uri
                retval, err = os.execute("rm \"" .. uri .. "\"")
            end
        end
        if (retval ~= nil) then removeItem() end
    else
        --windows, remove from playlist first so the file isnt locked by vlc
        removeItem()
        uri = string.gsub(uri, "/", "\\")
        retval, err = windowsDelete(uri,3,1)
    end

    if (retval == nil) then
        vlc.msg.info("[vlc-delete] error: " .. err)
        d = vlc.dialog("VLC Delete")
        d:add_label("Could not remove \"" .. uri .. "\"", 1, 1, 1, 1)
        d:add_label(err, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        d:add_button("OK", click_ok, 1, 3, 1, 1)
        d:show()
    end
end

function click_ok()
    d:delete()
    vlc.deactivate()
end

function deactivate()
    vlc.deactivate()
end

function close()
    deactivate()
end

function meta_changed()
end
```

---

https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/blob/master/wastebasket/dotlocal/share/vlc/lua/extensions/WasteBasket.lua

```
--[[
https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/blob/master/wastebasket/dotlocal/share/vlc/lua/extensions/WasteBasket.lua
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=108811
https://superuser.com/questions/721112/vlc-how-to-delete-file-on-disk#
INSTALLATION (create directories if they donot exist):
- put the file in the VLC subdir /lua/extensions, by default:
* Windows (all users): %ProgramFiles%\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\extensions\
* Windows (current user): %APPDATA%\VLC\lua\extensions\
* Linux (all users): /usr/share/vlc/lua/extensions/
* Linux (current user): ~/.local/share/vlc/lua/extensions/
* Mac OS X (all users): /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/extensions/
- Restart VLC.
- The extension can then be found in the menu:
    View > Move current playing file into wastebasket
]]--

--[[ Extension description ]]

function descriptor()
  return { title = "Wastebasket" ;
    version = "0.9" ;
    author = "Mark Morschhäuser/Ole Tange" ;
    shortdesc = "Move current playing file into wastebasket";
    description = "<h1>Wastebasket</h1>"
    .. "When you're playing a file, use Wastebasket to "
    .. "easily move this file to a .waste-dir with one click. "
    .. "<br>This will NOT change your playlist, it will move the file itself. "
    .. "<br>Wastebasket will search for a dir called .waste "
    .. "in the dir of the file and all parent dirs of that.";
    url = "https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/tree/master/wastebasket"
  }
end

--[[ Hooks ]]

-- Activation hook
function activate()
  local filename,dst,wdir = filename_dst_wastedir()
  if(directory_exists(wdir)) then
    d = vlc.dialog("Wastebasket")
    d:add_label("Move <b>".. filename .. "</b> to <b>" .. wdir .. "</b>?")
    d:add_button("Move", delete)
    d:add_button("Cancel", close)
    d:show()
  else
    d = vlc.dialog("Wastebasket - no dir found")
    d:add_label(".waste is not found anywhere in parent dirs")
    d:add_button("Cancel", close)
    d:show()
  end
  vlc.msg.dbg("[Wastebasket] Activated")
end

function filename_dst_wastedir()
  -- get the current playing file
  local item = vlc.input.item()
  -- extract its URI
  local uri = item:uri()
  -- decode %foo stuff from the URI
  local filename = vlc.strings.decode_uri(uri)
  -- remove 'file://' prefix which is 7 chars long
  filename = string.sub(filename,8)

  -- find .waste in parent dirs
  local wdir = wastedir(dirname(filename))
  return filename,wdir .. "/" .. basename(filename),wdir
end

function wastedir(dir)
  -- recursively search for .waste in parent dir

  vlc.msg.dbg("[Wastebasket/wastedir] Looking at " .. dir)
  local wdir = dir .. "/" .. ".waste"
  if directory_exists(wdir) then
     vlc.msg.dbg("[Wastebasket/wastedir] Found wastedir: " .. wdir)
     return wdir
  end
  -- try the parent dir
  local parent = dirname(dir)
  if(parent == dir) then
    -- we have reached root (/)
    -- return wdir (which does not exist)
    return wdir
  end
  vlc.msg.dbg("[Wastebasket/wastedir] parent " .. parent)
  if directory_exists(parent) then
    return wastedir(parent)
  else
    return parent
  end
end

function directory_exists(dir)
  -- Simple checker if dir exists
  -- shell quote the dirname
  dir, _ = dir:gsub("([\002-\009\011-\026\\#?`(){}%[%]^*<>=~|; \"!$&'\130-\255])", "\\%1")
  dir, _ = dir:gsub("\n", "'\n'")
  return os.execute("cd " .. dir)
end

function deactivate()
  -- Deactivation hook
  vlc.msg.dbg("[Wastebasket] Deactivated")
  vlc.deactivate()
end

function close()
  deactivate()
end

--- Function equivalent to basename in POSIX systems
--@param str the path string
function basename(str)
  local name = string.gsub(str, "(.*/)(.*)", "%2")
  return name
end

function dirname(str)
  local name = string.gsub(str, "(.*)/(.*)", "%1")
  return name
end

function delete()
  local filename,dst,wdir = filename_dst_wastedir()
  if(directory_exists(wdir)) then
    vlc.msg.dbg("[Wastebasket]: Move to " .. dst)
    local retval, err = os.rename(filename,dst)
    if(retval == nil) then
      -- error handling; if moving failed, print why
      vlc.msg.dbg("[Wastebasket] error: " .. err)
    end
  else
    d = vlc.dialog("Wastebasket - no dir found")
    d:add_label(".waste is not found anywhere in parent dirs")
    d:add_button("Cancel", close)
    d:show()
  end
  close()
end

-- This empty function is there, because vlc pested me otherwise
function meta_changed()
end
```

Comment: Seems obvious this is the only script of this topic visible to stay that I found, all others where useless dead(gitlab above fixed for now after my comment) or located at some website requiring some crap account to enter as posted below...

Answer (score 0):

None of those worked for me so I modified to : https://gist.github.com/e-desouza/9c340a5373492befb1203428e458bbf5 . Note, this is OSX only and doesn't have any warnings etc before deleting. To make it a shortcut:

OSX System Preference->Keyboard->Apps Shortcuts > + (Click the plus button and select the VLC app)

The menu title in case was "VLC Delete OSX" (minus the quotes) and use the shortcuts desired. (In my case I choose Ctrl+D)